# "display Surface quit" error when using OpenAI Gym in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to follow the tutorial here: https://github.com/microsoft/ML-For-Beginners/blob/main/8-Reinforcement/2-Gym/README.md
I can run the block of code 1 shown below once, but when I run this code or any other code which involves env.reset() and then env.render() again, I get "display Surface quit" error. I am using Mac OS.

```
env.reset()

for i in range(100):
   env.render()
   env.step(env.action_space.sample())
env.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render(mode='human')
    obs, rew, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
    if done:
       env.reset()
env.close()
```

this code doesn't work as you, but if you add the 2 first lines it works. Maybe Jupyter forget or don't actualize the env variable.

This is the good code :

```
import gym
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2',continuous=True)
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
     env.render(mode='human')
     obs, rew, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
     if done:
        env.reset()
env.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem before while working on jupyter notebook.
The fix was adding
`env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="human")` together with the loop in the same block